# IIS 7.5 - How To Grant Read/Write Access For A non-local Share To Application Pool

Tags: iis-7.5, pool

Everything I've found via search on this talks about Read/Write for local drives only (typically C) and what I am having trouble with is getting the same Read/Write access for an application pool to a non-local drive, specifically a share on the file server.

We've set the Application pool to run the anonymous user under a domain account that we have explicitly verified has full control of the file share and yet the web app that use the application pool is unable to access this non-local share.  It can however access a local copy of the shared folder if we copy the folder from the file server to the local drive.

This is a third party app and we'eve followed all the instructions from the vendor and so far this is unresolved.  Their support is looking at this but I don't believe they have any idea on what's wrong.  This same web app works fine with the same file server share when the web app is running under IIS6 on another sever so its something with IIS7.5.    I figure its got to be something particular to IIS7.5 that is not in IIS6 that is the key.

Ideas?

FYI - The application pool is already set to classic mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will have to see the permission that you have. In iss7.5 you have the aplication pool running with an account, It can be a ApplicationpoolIdnetity, or a real one. if you want to access the share the application pool identity has to have rights to do so, or you can impersonate a user and then use the permission that user has to copy to the shared folder, i prefere to use the impersonate, only when is necessary i do the impersonate and do whatever i most do.

Comment: The AP (app pool) is set to use a domain acct that is a member of the admins group.

This is a web app that has in the past run on IIs6.  Since this Windows 2008R2 its on IIS7.5 and so its setup to use IIS6 like functionality (i.e. the AP has its pipeline mode set to Classic and the Net Framework to v1.1).

The AP & the web app (under the default website) are set to use this domain acct.  The Basic Settings for the website (The connect AS) is set to this same domain acct.  The Anonymous Authentication is enabled and set to use this same domain acct for its credentials.

Thoughts?

Comment: And the domain account is a group admins, of your computer or in the domain? the acount that is used has permission of read/write in the share?

Comment: It is of the domain and has full control of the share.